# Are there any php functions/libs/etc to detect if a user is behind a proxy or not?

Tags: php, spam-prevention

I've been having a spam problem on my site, where people sign up and act extremely abusive to other users of my site. I can easy IP ban them, except they always come back under a different IP address through a proxy or TOR.

So I was curious if there are any php classes or functions that can look up the IP and determine if its a genuine user, or someone behind a proxy, in which case it would muzzle their accounts upon registration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*Many* legitimate users will come to you through proxies - are you sure you want to filter all of them out?  For example:

- ISPs that run caching proxies for all their users
- People on corporate networks

To answer your question, checking for the `X-Forwarded-For` or `Via` headers is probably your best bet.

Comment: +1 - blocking anyone behind a proxy just seems like a really bad idea and a poor thought out solution.

Comment: I didn't say block. It could mark them as potential spammers, and a moderator can closely examine the activities of these marked users.

Answer (score 2):

Following RichieHindle's answer, I'd suggest some kind of profanity filter/detection - detect the unacceptable behaviour and suspend the accounts. Use of a proxy could definitely influence weight of decisions made by the filter/detector!

Actually stopping them is difficult, but if their nasty content doesn't get published they'll soon give up.

Comment: Indeed.  Nothing a clbuttic profanity filter can't solve.  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=clbuttic